# How to read bytes from file to hex string in C++?

Tags: c++, char, hex, ifstream

I am trying to read a file which contains bytes into a hex string.

```
std::ifstream infile("data.txt", std::ios_base::binary);

int length = 10;
char char_arr[length];
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
     infile.get(char_arr[i]);
}
std::string hex_data(char_arr);
```

However the `hex_data` does not look like a hex string. Is there a way to convert the bytes to a hex string during reading?

Comment: Please show the input and output.

Comment: The `std::string` constructor that you are using requires a **null terminated** `char` array.

Comment: `int length = 10; char char_arr[length];` is not standard C++, see [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). Either make `length` const, or else use `new[]` or better `std::vector`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel only if you use the constructor that takes just a `char*` by itself. There is another constructor that accepts a length

Comment: @drescherjm the input file is binary, so there may not even be any "lines" to read from it. But, of course, there are ways to read from a binary data directly into a `std::string`. But that is pretty moot in this case.

Comment: I was hoping to see my first comment answered for me to understand the question but yes I did overlook the `std::ios_base::binary` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading in raw bytes and storing them as-is into your `std::string`.  If you want the `std::string` to be hex formatted, you need to handle that formatting yourself, eg:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::ifstream infile("data.txt", std::ios_base::binary);

const int length = 10;
unsigned char bytes[length];

if (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes), length)) {
    size_t numRead = infile.gcount();
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numRead; ++i) {
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned short>(bytes[i]);
    }
    std::string hex_data = oss.str();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use std::stringstream object

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << static_cast<int>( your_char);
std::string result( stream.str() );
```

Comment: You should use `std::ostringstream` instead for output-only operations like this. But more important, if the `char` is signed, and its high bit is 1, this will cause the `int` to sign-extend, producing unwanted results. For example, `0x80` will be printed as `ff80`. Use unsigned chars instead to avoid that.

Comment: I tried your code with `static_cast<unsigned short>(char(0x80))` but the result also `ff80` I had to go through a double conversion to break the effect of the strong point bit: `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(char(0x80)))`

Comment: Yes, scaling up a *signed* `char` to an `unsigned short` performs sign-extension, because the `char` is promoted to `int` first, then the result is casted. See [Standard C++ Behavior of Signed Char to Unsigned Int Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011632/). But note that in my code example, the data starts out as `unsigned char` to begin with, so the bytes don't need an extra cast to unsigned before then casted to `unsigned short`.